# Spring boot Kafka class deserialization - not in the trusted package

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, json-deserialization

I know this problem is very common, but after following different solutions I couldn't find any working one. I want to deserialize strings and also my custom class object when receiving the message in Kafka. With String is all good, but not with my Class. I've added trusted packages in consumer configurations (with `com.springmiddleware.entities` being the package where my class is):

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {


        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "foo");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "com.springmiddleware.entities");

        return props;
    }
```

I have this in my `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: foo
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties:
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: 'com.springmiddleware.entities'
```

And added these lines to `application.properties`

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=com.springmiddleware.entities
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer 
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.add.type.headers=false
```

But the following error keeps showing:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
>   deserializing key/value for partition topic2-0 at offset 1. If needed,
>   please seek past the record to continue consumption. Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class
>   'com.springmiddleware.entities.Crime' is not in the trusted packages:
>   [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this class is safe to
>   deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only
>   done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).

**UPDATE**

ReceiverConfig:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {


        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "foo");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "com.springmiddleware.entities");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, "false");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),  new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
Listener Class (Receiver): 

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${app.topic.foo}")
@Service
public class Receiver {


     private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
            return latch;
        }

   @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(@Payload Crime message) {

            System.out.println("Received " + message);
    }

   @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(@Payload String message) {

        System.out.println("Received " +  message);
}
```

Comment: What version of spring kafka are you using?

Comment: @NotaJD Hi, I'm using version 2.2.4

Comment: can you show the complete `Consumerconfig` file @TodorokiM

Comment: @Deadpool edited with the class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the Overloaded `JsonDeserializer` constructor

> Starting with version 2.2, you can explicitly configure the deserializer to use the supplied target type and ignore type information in headers by using one of the overloaded constructors that have a boolean useHeadersIfPresent (which is true by default).

**The following example shows how to do so:**

```
DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, Cat1> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props,
    new IntegerDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Cat1.class, false));
```

**Your Code :**

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(),  new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(Object.class,false));
}
```

And now use `@KafkaListener` at class level

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
@Service
public class MultiListenerBean {

@KafkaHandler
public void listen(Cat cat) {
    ...
}

@KafkaHandler
public void listen(Hat hat) {
    ...
}

@KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
public void delete(Object obj) {
    ...
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi thank you, but I need to use the deserializer without the class specified because I deserialize different types of object - strings and myclass, in my case.

Comment: thank you, now it doesn't give me that problem, but I have a different error. It tells me Error while processing: ConsumerRecord - org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Comment: Show the listener class, are you doing batch? @TodorokiM

Comment: Added listener class in the question

Comment: Add the default kafkahandler method @TodorokiM  and try that

Comment: Thanks, this way is working. Only problem is, I can't cast the object I'm receiving to my class. It throws an error saying that it cannot be cast to myclass because  is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader

Comment: Ok, I've tried printing the class of the obj I'm receiving and it's a LinkedHasMap. Any idea why?

Comment: Just add one more `@KafkaHandler` method with `LinkedHasMap` as argument and it's really blank to me what type of payload you have in that topic @TodorokiM, if you provide the appropriate POJO to payload it will work

Comment: Solved, I've used an ObjectMapper to convert the LinkedHashMap to my class object. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem too. Handled only `public void delete(Object obj)` method... `public void listen(Cat cat)` metod is not working. How to fix it?